# Does Google Glass Voice Trigger launch Service with Prompt?

Tags: android, service, google-glass

I'm setting up a POC app for Google Glass, using the new GDK sneak peek released this week. I can get an Activity to launch using a Voice Trigger and Prompt, but I cannot get a Service to launch with both. I can only launch a Service when using a Voice Trigger and NO prompt.

On other words, this will launch a Service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<trigger keyword="@string/glass_voice_trigger" />
```

But this won't:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<trigger keyword="@string/glass_voice_trigger">
    <input prompt="@string/glass_voice_prompt" />
</trigger>
```

I've checked the logs and in the second case the service just does not start at all (in the first case the service starts).

Anyone else having this problem? The samples released by Google (Compass, Timer, Stopwatch) all use a Voice Trigger to launch a service, none use a Voice Trigger + Prompt. I actually tried modifying Google's compass example to use a prompt as well, with the same result - the compass service did not start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Glass Live Card not inserting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100120/google-glass-live-card-not-inserting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, yes just saw that this is a duplicate of that post - [Google Glass Live Card not inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100120/google-glass-live-card-not-inserting)

Oh well, at least I know I'm not going crazy, and others found the same thing!